# Why is set.timeout not working in this php while loop?

Tags: javascript, php, while-loop, settimeout, window.open

I'm not very familiar with javascript. I would like to open every link in this while loop with a timeout. Without timeout it's working.

```
<?php
$zaehler = 23423423; // id aus dem forular
$anzahl = 5; // popups aus dem forumlar
$max = $zaehler + $anzahl; //  = maximale anzahl 

$increment = 1; // zählt die tradeid um 1 hoch

$i = 0;

while($zaehler < $max) {
    $i++;
    echo $i . " | ";
    $link = $zaehler += $increment;
    echo "https://mywebsite/" . $link;



    echo"<form action='https://mywebsite/$link' method='post' target='_blank'> <input type='submit'> </form>"; //irrelevant, da popups schon geöffnet werden

    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> 
        window.open('https://mywebsite/$link', '_blank', setTimeout(1000), )
    </script>";

    echo "<hr>";



    if($link == $max) {
      echo "<hr><br>Stop";
      break; //bricht die schleife ab, wenn maximale vorgegebene anzahl an popups erreicht ist
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: did you even read the documentation of `window.open` and `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot really use the `setTimeout()` function as you suggest...

I guess this is roughly what you are looking for:

```
echo <<< EOT
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.open('https://mywebsite/$link', '_blank');
    }, 1000);
</script>
EOT;
```

Note: I just use the `nowdoc` notation since it is easier to read. Certainly it is possible to use a normal literal string for the echo command too.

Answer (score 0):

If you read about `window.open` carefully, for example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), you will see that third argument of it is not something connected with `setTimeout`.

Proper code for opening your window via `settimeout` is:

```
window.setTimeout(
    // what to do:
    function() { window.open('https://mywebsite/url', 'WINDOW_NAME')  },
    // in what amount of time:
    1000
);
```